# Calculating levenshtein distance for 200k strings with python

Tags: python, optimization

I have big MongoDB database of 200k+ recodrs of names and surnames.

How can I optimize procedure of adding new record, if before insertion I want to calc levinstein distance for all the 200k+ records and to make an insertion only if it's higher than the trashhold to escape collision (this means, that name and surname of the new record can be slightly different due to some translation mistakes, but still it would be the same person).

The data about people is grabbed from different sources, so I want information for the same person not to be duplicated and scattered accros the database.

Comment: Very bad idea to check for same person by comparing name and surname : homonyms are not rare. Even by adding birthday it would not be 100% bullet proof. So using Levenstein distance here adds nothing but more risks to find erroneously "quasi" homonyms.

Comment: So how can I escape a collision and to keep statistics from different sources about each person assigned to one person? 

Is there anything possible to do, except for manual validation of surname and name?

Comment: Since this will not be any accurate at all (lots of false positives and false negatives guaranteed) you could, e.g., just as well assume that there will be no typo or misspelling on the first character of the name (you'd notice that) and compare only to those with the same initial.

Comment: Also, if the names are your only attribute, there _will_ be collisions. Not only are there people with the same name, but also people with just so slightly different names. Your system would detect tons of false positives. If you have other attributes, such as date of birth, compare only to those with same date of birth.